# EF Core self-referencing one-to-many with set null on delete and cascade on update may cause cycles or multiple paths

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

So, what I'm trying to create is a relationship in which I have an entity (`ProductCategory`), which has an One-to-many relationship with itself. This works well when I have no action OnDelete and OnUpdate, but I would like the `ParentId` (the foreign key) to be set null when the parent is deleted (SetNull OnDelete) and cascade on Update.

Unfortunately, when I try to run the migration, I get the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ProductCategories_ProductCategories_ParentId' on table 'ProductCategories' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Here is the code I use:

```cs
public class ProductCategory
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductCategory Parent { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<ProductCategory> Children { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    // ...

    modelBuilder.Entity<ProductCategory>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        entity.Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");
        entity.Property(t => t.ParentId)
            .HasDefaultValue(null);
        entity.HasIndex(t => t.Slug)
            .IsUnique();
        entity.HasMany(t => t.Children)
            .WithOne(c => c.Parent)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull)
            .IsRequired(false);
        entity.HasMany(t => t.Products)
            .WithOne(p => p.Category)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull)
            .IsRequired(false);
    });
}
```

By the way, if it has any consequence, I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: https://medium.com/@dmitry.pavlov/tree-structure-in-ef-core-how-to-configure-a-self-referencing-table-and-use-it-53effad60bf